# Java API to query CommonCrawl to populate Digital Object Identifier (DOI) Database

Tags: web-scraping, common-crawl

I am attempting to create a database of Digital Object Identifier (DOI) found on the internet.

By manually searching the `CommonCrawl` Index Server manually I have obtained some promising results.

However I wish to develop a programmatic solution.

This may result in my process only requiring to read the index files and not the underlying WARC data files.

The manual steps I wish to automate are these:-

1). for each `CommonCrawl` Currently available index collection(s):

2). I search ... "`Search a url in this collection: (Wildcards -- Prefix: http://example.com/*   Domain: *.example.com)` " e.g. `link.springer.com/*`

3). this returns almost 6MB of json data that contains approx 22K unique DOIs.

How can I **browse** all available `CommonCrawl` indexes instead of **searching** for specific URLs?

From reading the API documentation for CommonCrawl I cannot see how I can browse all the indexes to extract all DOIs for all domains.

UPDATE

I found this example java code https://github.com/Smerity/cc-warc-examples/blob/master/src/org/commoncrawl/examples/S3ReaderTest.java

that shows how to access a common crawl dataset.

However when I run it I receive this exception

```
"main" org.jets3t.service.S3ServiceException: Service Error Message. -- ResponseCode: 404, ResponseStatus: Not Found, XML Error Message: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><Error><Code>NoSuchKey</Code><Message>The specified key does not exist.</Message><Key>common-crawl/crawl-data/CC-MAIN-2016-26/segments/1466783399106.96/warc/CC-MAIN-20160624154959-00160-ip-10-164-35-72.ec2.internal.warc.gz</Key><RequestId>1FEFC14E80D871DE</RequestId><HostId>yfmhUAwkdNeGpYPWZHakSyb5rdtrlSMjuT5tVW/Pfu440jvufLuuTBPC25vIPDr4Cd5x4ruSCHQ=</HostId></Error>
```

In fact every file I try to read results in the same error. Why is that?

what is the correct common crawl uri's for their datasets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the example code to work replace lines 24 and 25 with:

```
String fn = "crawl-data/CC-MAIN-2013-48/segments/1386163035819/warc/CC-MAIN-20131204131715-00000-ip-10-33-133-15.ec2.internal.warc.gz";
S3Object f = s3s.getObject("commoncrawl", fn, null, null, null, null, null, null);
```

Also note that the commoncrawl group have [an updated example](https://github.com/commoncrawl/cc-warc-examples/blob/master/src/org/commoncrawl/examples/S3ReaderTest.java).

Comment: how to read to an offset within a WARC file using s3 java library? I get  Mark not supported when calling "archiveReader.get(10L)"

Comment: I don't know. You may want to post a new question. But if you have a look at the docs for [S3Object.getObject](https://jets3t.s3.amazonaws.com/api/org/jets3t/service/S3Service.html#getObject-org.jets3t.service.model.S3Bucket-java.lang.String-java.util.Calendar-java.util.Calendar-java.lang.String:A-java.lang.String:A-java.lang.Long-java.lang.Long-) you might find an answer - it looks like the method accepts offset arguments.

Answer (score 2):

The data set location has changed since more than one year, see [announcement](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/common-crawl/nKuQK68rebo/discussion). However, many examples and libraries still contain the old pointers. You can access the index files for all crawls back to 2013 on `s3://commoncrawl/cc-index/collections/CC-MAIN-YYYY-WW/indexes/cdx-00xxx.gz` - replace `YYYY-WW` with year and week of the crawle and expand `xxx` to 000-299 to get all 300 index parts. New crawl data is announced on the [Common Crawl group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/common-crawl), or read more about [how to access the data](http://commoncrawl.org/the-data/get-started/).

Comment: I can now get https://commoncrawl.s3.amazonaws.com/crawl-data/CC-MAIN-2016-18/segments/1461860106452.21/warc/CC-MAIN-20160428161506-00000-ip-10-239-7-51.ec2.internal.warc.gz however when I try with s3://commoncrawl/ prefix my java code (show above) still gives the same error. Do I need to set up an Amazon account event to access public s3 datasets via this code?

Comment: It's possible to access the data without an AWS account. Easiest, using the [AWS CLI](https://aws.amazon.com/cli/) and `aws --no-sign-request s3 ...`. The [cc-warc-examples](https://github.com/commoncrawl/cc-warc-examples) are supposed to run from a Hadoop cluster on AWS in the us-east-1 region where the Common Crawl data is hosted.